# How to get array value join related array value?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am newly php developer, i have worked on codeigniter project, get data from database below

```
Array(
  [0]=>(
          [id]=>1,
          [no_of_services]=>guide,assistant
),
[services]=>(
      [id]=>1,,
      [quote_id]=>1,
      [tour_reference]=>GD/Amsterdam/2019
))
```

But i need to required below this:

```
    Array(
  [0]=>(
          [id]=>1,
          [no_of_services]=>guide,assistant,
          [services]=>(
      [id]=>1,,
      [quote_id]=>1,
      [tour_reference]=>GD/Amsterdam/2019
)
),
)
```

Please help me how to array of inner array function
Thanks Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not processing the data retrieved from database, correctly.
We could help you more, only if you provide your code snippet here.

However you can transform your array by using following steps:

1) Initialize a new empty array named $output

2) Iterate your database result array in a 'for' loop

3) In 'for' loop, do operations to insert in $output array as per your desired format.

4) In the end, $output array is your desired array.